# JQuery animate with properties based on id of element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate multiple JQuery elements, but base properties off of the id of the element, running a callback function once the animations are complete.

I have thought about creating a loop for it, but that would not work as I want the completion function to run only once.

This is not exactly what I'm doing, but I think it shows the point.
For HTML:

```
<div id = "n1">1</div>
<div id = "n2">2</div>
<div id = "n3">3</div>
<button>Go</button>
```

The Script:

```
function complete() {
    //does something
}
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({width: String(id.charAt(1) * 10) + "%"}, 500, null, complete);
});
```

But I'm not sure how to actually get the id.

If that worked, I would have three bars with their width 10%, 20%, and 30%.

Thank you!

Edit: I realized I could loop it and run the completion with a timeout. Should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a **wrapper** around all your divs:

```
<div class=wrapper>
    <div id = "n1">1</div>
    <div id = "n2">2</div>
    <div id = "n3">3</div>
</div>
<button>Go</button>
```

Make sure your divs have some height and width **styling** to start with:

```
#n1, #n2, #n3 {
  width:100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green
}
```

Have your **complete function** as needed:

```
function complete() {
    alert("done")
}
```

...then **apply animation event to each div**, using a **Boolean to ensure the callback is only called once**:

```
var done = false;
$("button").click(function() {

$(".wrapper").find('div').each(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id')
    width = String(id.charAt(1) * 10) + "%"
    $(this).animate({width: width}, 500, function() {
    if(!done) {
    done = true;
    complete()
    }
    })
})

})
```

**Result**:

[image]

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/zwo79ype/1/)

Comment: So where would I put the `complete` function?

Comment: Sorry, see answer now.

Answer (score 0):

> **How to let the completion function to run only once?**

No, the complete event will fired for each object, so for your sample, there will fire 3 times. But we can use a counter to process what you want to do only once.

```
var counter = 0;
var total = 3;

function complete() {
  counter += 1;
  if (counter==total){
    //does something
  }
}
```

> **How to get the id?**

In the onClick event, you can get the DOM object by `this`, so you can get it's id simply call `$(this).attr("id")`

> **Full code**

```
var counter = 0;
var total = 0;

function complete() {
    counter += 1;

if (!total) total = $("div[id^=n]").length;

if (counter==total){
    //does something
}

$("button").click(function() {

    $("div[id^=n]").each(function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        width = String(id.charAt(1) * 10) + "%";
        $(this).animate({width: width}, 500, complete);
    });

});
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rock2cp/rcqLu7et/) :